# Complex number $z=cis(\frac{2k\pi}{5})$ for any integer $k$ such that $z \ne 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Consider the complex number $z=cis(\frac{2k\pi}{5})$ for any integer $k$ such that $z \ne 1$.

(a) Show that $z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}=2\cos(\frac{2nk\pi}{5})$ for any integer $n$.

(b) Show that $z^5=1$. Hence, or otherwise, show that $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$.

(c) Find the value of $b$, given that $(z+\frac{1}{z})^2+(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2})^2=b$.

My approach:

(a) This was easy, I rewrote this as $z^n+z^{-n}$, applied De Moivre's theorem, the sines cancelled out and that was all.

(b) I proved the first part that $z^5=1$, but have trouble with the second part ("hence, or otherwise...") - I tried rewritting a term, say the term $z$, as $cis(\frac{2k\pi}{5}))=cis(\frac{1}{5}*2k\pi)=(cis(2k\pi))^{1/5}=1^{1/5}=1$. This, I thought, will make all the terms be equal to 1. But the first sentence of the exercise says "for any integer $k$ such that $z\ne1$" - but how is it even possible? No matter what value of $k$ I substitute, it will always be a multiple of $2\pi$ so the $cis$ will be 1. What am I missing? How do I solve that?

(c) I think that I should use (a) here but I got stuck.

Comment: Why doesn't $\cis$ work?

Comment: I don't know, $\cos$ works but $\cis$ doesn't.

Comment: Probably because $\cis$ is rather uncommon, $\cis z=e^iz$, which is shorter.

Comment: @RichardSmith. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing my answers according to the questions you have asked. The first question has been properly answered by you. So I start with the second one.

1. The mistake you have made in this solution is when you write:

> $$1^\frac15=1$$

Truly speaking, $1^\frac15$ has $5$ values, of which $1$ is one of the values and the only real value. The other $4$ values are complex .

The solution should be worked out as follows:
$$z=cis (\frac{2k\pi}{5})$$
$$z^5=\left[cis (\frac{2k\pi}{5})\right]^5$$
By De-Moivre's Theorem,$$z^5=cis \left(\frac{5\cdot 2k\pi}{5}\right)=cis  (2k\pi)$$
$$z^5=cis  (2k\pi)=\cos 2k\pi +i \sin 2k\pi=1 \, \forall \, k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
And for the second part, use the factorisation:
$$z^5-1=0$$
$$(z-1)(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4)=0$$ and you have already mentioned that $z \not = 1$.

2. The third one is simple and uses result (a).
   $$\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^2$$
   $$=\left[2\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}{5}\right)\right]^2+\left[2\cos \left(\frac{4k\pi}{5}\right)\right]^2$$

Hope you can complete it now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful, but I have two more questions: 1) In (b) it says "hence, or otherwise" - where "hence" refers to (a) - I guess that the factorization method is probably easier but how can you do (b) using (a)?. 2) Is it possible to simplify the result in (c)?

Comment: 1) Your interpretation is wrong. "Hence" means proving the 2nd part using the result of the 1st part i.e. show that $z^5=1$ and "otherwise" means without using that result. 2) Yes, of course. It will come out to be $3$. Try it. Simple trigonometry.

Comment: @RichardSmith Does the hint help you?

Comment: I understand your solution, but what hint do you mean?

Comment: @RichardSmith By hint, I meant the clarification I added in my last comment. If it was clear enough or not..... :-)

Comment: Ah, yea, it's clear, I don't know why I misinterpreted "hence". :) By the way, did you obtain the $3$ that (c) simplifies to without calculator? I see it should be 3 but can I calculate it by myself fast without using some fancy formulas for multiplies of angles, etc?

Comment: @RichardSmith It can be done without calculator. However, it requires using some formulae regarding multiple angles. If you are in a time crunch, you can prefer the way Joanpemo has followed. Still, that would require you to prove that the roots of order 5 are a cyclic multiplicative group.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

By Demoivre's theorem we can prove $z^5=1$ note important result that summation of roots of unity is $0$ and yes you are right use a part for part c ie $\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=\cos(x)$ use this

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$z^5=1\iff 0=z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$$

and since $\;z\neq1\;$ you get (b)

For (c) you can indeed use (b), and remember that all the roots of order $\;5\;$ are a cyclic (multiplicative) group, so

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=1+\overbrace{z}^{=z^{-4}}+z^2+z^{-2}+\overbrace{z^4}^{=z^{-1}}=\left(z+\frac1z\right)^2-1+\left(z^2+\frac1{z^2}\right)^2-2$$